# How do I get my footer to not block my div section in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I uploaded a picture of the issue.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMHM2.png

### ---------

```
    #footer{
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background:#951;
}
#content{
     width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left; 
}
```

---

If anyone can tell me the issue or have any advice I'd appreciate it very much. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that the `float: left;` may be causing this. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: HTML code? is your footer in the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest solution would be to add some spacing at the bottom to sort of push down the viewport:

```
#content{
  margin-bottom: 150px; /* <-- Adjust if necessary */
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left; 
}
```

Comment: Just tweaked with it little and is working great now. Thank you!